# Copy the list of invitees between two events through apex

Tags: apex, trigger, event

I need to copy the list of invitees between two events in Salesforce. I have one event created with a list of invitees leads and contacts. I want to copy that list to another event. Is it possible? How can I do that using apex trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's possible. You will need to create copies of the `EventRelation` records related to the original Event.

The documentation on EventRelation can be found  here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm

So basically follow these steps in your trigger:

1. collect all event id's of events that are in the trigger
2. query all related EventRelation records and put them in a map (grouped by EventId). For a list of fields to query, check the documentation in the url.
3. go through the event id's one by one and make a clone (without Id) of all of the EventRelation records, updating the eventId on the EventRelation to the new Event's Id
4. Insert the new set of EventRelation records